# How much time do we gain?

Tags: calculus

It takes $6.5$ hours to load a ship using $4$ cranes.

Suppose we start with $4$ cranes, but use an additional crane $2.5$ hours after starting.  How much faster is loading using $5$ cranes in this way compared to using just the $4$ cranes ($6.5$ hours)?

---

$$$$

I have done the following:

In one hour the $4$ cranes make $\frac{4}{6.5}$ of the work.

The first $2,5$ hours we have $4$ cranes so they have done $\frac{4}{6.5}\cdot 2,5$ of the work.

Then we can have $5$ cranes. They make $\frac{5}{6,5}$ of work per hour?

Let $x$ be the hours that we have $5$ cranes. Then the rest of the work is $\frac{5}{6,5}\cdot x$.

They have to do what the $4$ cranes make in $6,5$ hours, so does this mean that $\frac{4}{6.5}\cdot 2.5+\frac{5}{6.5}\cdot x=\frac{4}{6.5}\cdot 6.5 \Rightarrow \frac{4}{6.5}\cdot 2.5+\frac{5}{6.5}\cdot x=4$ ?

Comment: What does "To stevedorenaut a ship" mean?

Comment: It was meant "to upload a ship". I edited it. Do you have an idea? @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Is what I have done so far correct? @DavidG.Stork

Comment: And what is "canes"?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry! @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Canes is obviously a typo where "cranes" was meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading rate of a single crane (boatloads per hour) is:

$r = {1 \over 4 \times 6.5}$.

In the $5$-crane case we have over time $t$ that the work done is:

$t \times 4 \times r + (t-2.5) \times 1 \times r = 1$ (boat) because four cranes work for $t$ hours and 1 crane works for $t-2.5$ hours.

Solve for $t$ to get the total time.  Then calculate $6.5 -t$ to find how much time was saved using crane $5$.

Comment: Why isn't it $t \times 4 \times r + (t-2.5) \times 1 \times r= 1$ ?

Comment: Yep.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok!! I see!! Thank you so much!! :-)